# how to Verify phone number with RegExp in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, cypress

I am trying to verify my phone number in Cypress to match my regExp. How do I solve this problem?

#### Attempt 1

```
cy.get('#FormField_7_input')
    .contains(/^\d{2}([ .-]?)\d{2}(?:\1\d{2}){3}$/gmu)
```

The above code displayed this error:

[image: Contains Command]

#### Attempt 2

```
cy.get('#FormField_7_input')
    .should('match', /^\d{2}([ .-]?)\d{2}(?:\1\d{2}){3}$/gmu)
```

The above code displayed this error:

[image: Assertion command - should]

Comment: Look like you are getting the input element, you need to extract the value out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the value what needed for my code to work

```
cy.get('#FormField_7_input')
.invoke('val')
.should('match', /^\d{2}([ .-]?)\d{2}(?:\1\d{2}){3}$/gmu)
```

Thank you once more.